# Cannot kill mongodb process

Tags: kill, mongodb

I am trying everything but every time I kill the mongod process it starts a new one in a different PID. I even uninstalled it, but still I have the same behavior.

When I run this I get

```
ps -ef | grep mongod

999       8260  8242  1 01:24 ?        00:00:01 mongod --replSet=bigchain-rs
alomejor  8436  5209  0 01:26 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mongod
```

So then I try `sudo kill 8260` and a new instance of mongo is created in another PID. Also tried `sudo kill -2 8260`

When I try `mongod --shutdown` I get:

```
There doesn't seem to be a server running with dbpath: /data/db
```

Might be because of the 999 user?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried terminate the service itself:

```
mongod --shutdown
```

If you are in macOS and using `brew`:

```
brew services stop mongodb
```

Comment: I just edited my question. This is not an answer anymore